# How to batch rename a directory of files?

Tags: files-and-directories

I have a directory of files with the pattern: `"some_number.some_name.pdf"`
I want to remove the `"some_number."` part from all the files. How to do that?
There are a few commands in my head: `FileNames`, `Map`, etc. But I don't know how to chain them together to achieve the task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `?Rename*`; `?StringR*` and give it a shot. Its not a very difficult problem really.

Comment: Other useful functions involve `?Regular*`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I [mentioned](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14902/how-to-batch-rename-a-directory-of-files#comment44104_14903) in a comment, using string patterns makes for lot cleaner code. Here's a simple way to do it using `StringCases`:

```
changeFileName = StringCases[#, NumberString ~~ "." ~~ f__ :> f] &;
changeFileName@"1234.name.pdf"
(* {"name.pdf"} *)
```

If you have a list of file names, map the above onto the list.

You can progressively build upon this for more complicated filename patterns. However, for the requirements in the question, this is adequate.

Answer (score 5):

A pure function to make the changes to a filename string:

```
 fileNameChangeF = StringJoin@ Riffle[
   Pick[#, StringFreeQ[#, __ ~~ "_" ~~ NumberString] & /@ #] &@#,"."] &@
      StringSplit[#, "."] &
```

example:

```
 filenameList = {"abc_1234.xyz_name1.pdf",   "abc_1234.xyz_222.aaa_name2.pdf",
      "some_name.pdf"}
 fileNameChangeF/@filenameList
 (* {"xyz_name1.pdf", "aaa_name2.pdf", "some_name.pdf"} *)
```

**EDIT:** what the function does step-by-step:

```
 filenameList[[1]] (* input filename string *)
 (* "abc_1234.xyz_name1.pdf" *)
 StringSplit[#, "."] &[%] (* split at "."s *)
 (* {"abc_1234","xyz_name1","pdf"} *)
 StringFreeQ[#, __ ~~ "_" ~~ NumberString] & /@ % 
    (* find the parts free of the pattern *)
 (*{False,True,True} *)
 Pick[%%, %] (* pick those parts *)
 (* {"xyz_name1","pdf"}*)
 Riffle[%, "."] (* insert "."s back in *)
 (* {"xyz_name1",".","pdf"} *)
 StringJoin[%] (* ... and join *)
 (* "xyz_name1.pdf" *)
```

Mapped to a list of filenames `fileNameChangeF/@filenameList`, it does the same operations on each filename.

Comment: obviously a good answer but pretty scary nonetheless!

Comment: Wow when i fully understand this oneliner i'll learn some good stuff from Mathematica. Thanks !

Comment: @chris, updated to make it dispell the scare :)

Comment: @kguler have you ever considered competing for the one-liner competition? :-)

Comment: @chris, may be next year, need to get some practice using `f` instead of `fileNameChangeF` (among other things.) :)

Comment: For guys who like regexes: `RegularExpression["(?s).+_(\\d)+"]`

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I'd do it.  Hopefully it's general enough, and easy to understand.

Start by defining a base directory:

```
 base = "c:\\mse\\test\\";
```

I usually use `Import` to get a list of filenames.  If you give it a directory name, it will return a list of all the files under that directory (including subdirectories):

```
original = Import[base]
```

> `{"1.alice.pdf", "2.bob.pdf", "30.charlie.pdf"}`

Then we can use a string expressions and a rule to transform the names:

```
renamed = StringReplace[original, NumberString .. ~~ "." ~~ name__ ~~ ".pdf" ->
  name ~~ ".pdf"]
```

> `{"alice.pdf", "bob.pdf", "charlie.pdf"}`

Finally take the two lists and rename the files.  It's probably clearest to use a `Table`:

```
Table[RenameFile[base <> original[[i]], base <> renamed[[i]]], {i, Length[original]}]
```

Comment: For regex fans: `StringReplace[original, RegularExpression["(\\d)+\\."] -> ""]`

Answer (score 3):

Just for guidance, you could

```
SetDirectory["~/tmp/"]

ff = FileNames["*.pdf"]

{01.toto01.pdf,02.toto02.pdf}
```

Try it with a fake function to be sure

```
Map[RenameFile1[#, StringDrop[#, 3]] &, ff]
```

If it does what you want do it for real

```
Map[RenameFile[#, StringDrop[#, 3]] &, ff]
```

Comment: I would rather use string patterns to drop the prefix instead of `StringDrop`. The latter assumes that all prefixes are of the same length, which may not be true.

Comment: @rm-rf sure. I would rather not do it myself though and let the OP do what he wants ;-) Feel free to edit/remove my answer in any case.

Comment: @chris He may have more than 99 `pdf` files in his directory.  I recommend `StringTake[#, First@First@StringPosition[#, "."] - StringLength[#]] &`

Comment: How to use string patterns to do this ?

Comment: @user4714 I don't see why you would use patterns, since the numbers are always at the beginning of the string.  There's no need to always use pattern matching.

Comment: @VF1 thanks but just for my learning purposes

Comment: @user4714 There's a whole guide in the docs for that.  But, tbh, I find myself using `RegularExpression[(* Regex *)]` most of the time anyway.