# How to Export from ParallelDo?

Tags: export, parallelization

I'm running a simulation with parallel, and I want the results from each parameter set exported to a file whenever it's done (because the parameter space is huge and my computer doesn't have enough memory to keep all the results). This is the code I tried:

```
output = OpenWrite["file.txt", PageWidth -> Infinity];
WriteString[output, "certain text"]; 
WriteString[output, "\n"]; 
ParallelDo[
 myarray=myfunction[i,j,k];
 Export[output, myarray // N, "CSV"];
 WriteString[output, "\n"],
{i,5},{j,4},{k,3}
]
```

Unfortunately I keep getting this error message which I don't understand:

> CharacterEncoding is not a known option for OutputStream[file.txt,82].

The problem does not occur when I use `Do` instead of `ParallelDo`. So I'm guessing it's got something to do with parallelization. What am I missing here?

--------edit----------

Apparently when I use `PutAppend` I don't get any error message, but I can't figure out how to remove the quotation marks and the line brakes in the middle of the data.

Comment: Multiple writes to the same file are most often problematic. To me it seems like each parallel kernel should write its own file then you join them later. If the execution order matters, you may want to use a  `Method -> "CoarsestGrained"`

Comment: Regarding your EDIT section: [PutAppend with PageWidth -> Infinity](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6441361/590388).

Comment: You might be interested in this [Writing data to a common file during parallel processing](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27189/writing-data-to-a-common-file-during-parallel-processing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `output` variable lives on the main kernel.  This variable is special, it represents an open file. *It cannot be used on the parallel kernels if the file was opened on the main kernel.*

Is it still possible to write to the same file *in parallel* from multiple different kernels?  Yes, but to do it robustly you must use an advanced parallel programming concept: [locks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) and [`CriticalSection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CriticalSection.html).  This is not only complicated, but it can also have detrimental effect on performance in Mathematica.

So why do you want to write to the *same file* from all subkernels?  I would write to a different file from each subkernel, then merge those files at the end if necessary.  To build a unique file name for each subkernel, you can use their `$KernelID`.

Comment: +1 For example, `file = "output"<>ToString[$ProcessID]<>".dat"`

Comment: @ChrisDegnen Thanks!  I updated the answer and suggested `$KernelID`.