# Elegant ways of solving this file batching task

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, export, import, map

There are a batch of data files in a folder (`dir = "D:\\Documents\\datadir"`), each of which consists of a list of data items, one per line. Each data item is a pair with the first component being either 0 or 1.

Now I want to

- import all the data files
- for each data file, extract the second components from the data items with their first components being 1
- export all the data files into a new folder (`newdir = "D:\\Documents\\newdatadir"`), using their individual original file names.

> What elegant ways would you take to solve this file batching task?
>   In particular, how to use `Map` to solve it (see my failure below)?

---

Using `Do`, I solve it as follows:

```
Do[
 data = Cases[Import[dir <> "\\" <> file, {"Data"}], {x_, _} /; x == 1][[All, 2]];
 Export[newdir <> "\\" <> file, data];
 ,
 {file, Import[dir]}
 ]
```

Using `Map`, I can only import and process the data and *failed to export them with their individual original file names*:

```
Map[Function[Cases[#, {x_, _} /; x == 1][[All, 2]]], Map[Function[Import[dir <> "\\" <> #, {"Data"}]], Import[dir]]]
```

---

*Possible test case for data files ("\\" for "\newline"):*

```
data1.txt: 0 20 \\ 1 21 \\ 0 200 \\ 1 211 \\ 1 2111
data2.txt: 1 21 \\ 1 2111 \\ 0 20 \\ 1 21 \\ 0 2000
```

---

*Related posts:*

- [How to batch rename a directory of files?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14902/22068) only renames a batch of files.
- [How to import all files of a folder at once?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5242/22068) only imports a batch of files.

Answer (score 3):

Try some thing like this:

```
SetDirectory[dir];
files = FileNames["*.txt"];
Export[newdir <> "\\" <> files[[#]], 
   Cases[Import[files[[#]]], {1, _}][[;; , 2]]] & /@ 
 Range[Length[files]]
```